# zlib.vcproj missing while installing Cairo for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cairo

I'm following this guide to download and install Cairo
https://www.cairographics.org/end_to_end_build_for_win32/

I'm in Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, when i need (following the guide) to copy the zlib.vcproj file the cmd can't find it.

In the guide

BUILD ZLIB

```
   mkdir %ROOTDIR%\zlib\projects\visualc71
   cd %ROOTDIR%\zlib\projects\visualc71
   copy %ROOTDIR%\libpng\projects\visualc71\zlib.vcproj
```

Comment: Those are very old instructions VC7.1 was 2003 I believe.

Comment: It's probably better to use vcpkg for this. I see it has cairo. https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: I would agree with @drescherjm the guide you linked in your question is very out of date and the github link would be a better option to look into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install vcpkg, a command-line package manager, from GitHub.com. And use a one liner command to install the cairo package for use with VS 2017 like so. It makes almost effortless to install many open source libraries.

```
.\vcpkg install cairo:x64-windows
```

Comment: I'm trying to use vcpkg, I read that, using .\vcpkg integrate install, i can include cairo in every c++ program, but i still can't include it.

Comment: @FabrizioApuzzo You may want to ask a new question about that showing the steps you did in vcpkg and the problem you are having including it. Make sure you tag the new question for vcpkg. I expect that will attract people who are more skilled in vcpkg than I. BTW, I have tested vcpkg however that was with CMake based Visual Studio projects. I don't use direct Visual Studio integration at all.

Comment: @FabrizioApuzzo: Use `.\vcpkg integrate install` to auto link installed packages to your c++ programs. Otherwise you can manually link.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, i' ve just solved using vcpkg (i didn't install english supports)